# Configuring JNotify on Windows

Tags: java, directory

I am using Java JNotify to listen for directories events.

However, whenever i'm running the program below, the program is terminating immediately with no error nothing

Instead, i think the program should wait for events

```
import net.contentobjects.jnotify.*;


public class ListenFile 
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws JNotifyException
    {
        String path = "C:/Users/noor/Desktop/Files";
        int mask =  JNotify.FILE_CREATED | 
        JNotify.FILE_DELETED | 
        JNotify.FILE_MODIFIED| 
        JNotify.FILE_RENAMED;

        boolean watchSubtree = true;
        int watchID = JNotify.addWatch(path, mask, watchSubtree, new JNotifyListener(){

            @Override
            public void fileCreated(int arg0, String arg1, String arg2) {

                System.out.println("1");
            }

            @Override
            public void fileDeleted(int arg0, String arg1, String arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("2");
            }

            @Override
            public void fileModified(int arg0, String arg1, String arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("3");
            }

            @Override
            public void fileRenamed(int arg0, String arg1, String arg2,
                    String arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("4");
            }});
        try
        {
                Thread.sleep(1000000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e1)
        {
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to add your program?

Comment: Here's part of the program, however in this i'm only trying jnotify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program needs to enter a `while (true) {};` loop or some other loop after the `catch` clause that will not let the application terminate.